# Explorer is randomly becoming unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I have no idea what this issue is, but at random times when I'm using my PC Explorer will NOT respond to any clicks, and sometimes on browsers when I click a tab it will close it instead of switching to that tab.

To fix it I always need to press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`DEL` and click cancel for everything to start responding properly again, and for tabs to stop closing on browsers when I click them.

I'm running Windows 10, and this issue has also occurred in Windows 7 before I upgraded, is this a Hardware or Software issue?

Comment: The only time I have experienced this type of behavior is Windows was encountering I/O errors due to a bad HDD.

Comment: So it's a warning sign of HD failure?

Comment: You should verify that on your own.

Comment: the tag should probably be "internet explorer" not "windows explorer." Also: ctrl+alt+del may be suspending javascript..

Comment: Next time it hangs can you create a full process dump of the process.  I would suggest use Procdump - https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx.  Use `procdump -accepteula -ma -h iexeplore.exe`  Hopefully that will create a dump.  If not, maybe explicitly force the dump without using -h.

Comment: VirtualHat - Come on with more specs on this device too. What hardware are you using exactly? You working with 1 GB of RAM or 16 GB or RAM for example? Have you looked over any Event Viewer logs or done any troubleshooting on your own yet by chance such as `chkdsk` or a memory scan, etc. What have you already done since as of right now, ***even with this bounty***, your details are vague and the potential answers could be anything so very broad. I would suggest you [edit] your question and add your specs and what you've already done and ruled out to get more action from others on this.

Comment: @Yorik Yes, this should way "internet explorer" as explorer is an entirely different program.

Comment: I have literally realised the mistake, sorry! Also im working with 8GB RAM

Comment: Please try using a different browser and see if anything happens. That will answer the question of whether or not it's a hardware/software issue.

Comment: Btw this has NOTHING  to do with I.E

Comment: Try to replace your mouse and keyboard.

Comment: You are saying _"it has nothing to do with IE"_ but you are also saying _"I click a tab it will close"_. I have no idea what you mean with your _PC Explorer_, and the Windows File Explorer has no multiple tabs it could close. So it is quite unclear what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if any plugins/adons are crashing the tab? Silverlight and Flash are sometimes really resource intensive or bad coding of the flash/silverlight content results in hangs. Try disabling all addons and re-enable one-by-one.

Another suggestion is to try unchecking the **Automatically detect settings** under **Internet Options** - **Connection** - **LAN Settings**. Internet Options are found in the IE Settings or via the Control Panel. This usually resolves compatibility issues related to network communication with WebDAV sites among others.